# How realistic is V The Serial?

Tags: realism, v-the-serial

[V The Serial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_The_Serial) is an Indian soap opera based on the real life of Indian TV actors. How much of the show is real? Are there any non-celebrity character that are also played by the same person? How real is the show?

Comment: @Mistu4u thanx for the edit

Comment: `I mean are there any non celebrity character that is also played by the same person?` I am not getting this part! The real life stories of stars are only being shown here, nothing else!

Comment: There are some more charter there in serial which are not celebrities specially Raj's gf and  Rohan's family etc. So i want to know that are they real person acting their own life?

Comment: And some of the events looks so unrealiostic that i doubt about it.

Comment: Hm, I get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's based on the real lives of the actors and get recreated. So they cast come actors to play real people, like Raj's ex girlfriend was Swati Semwal played by Peehu .